# Resolve promise with an object with a "then" function

Tags: angularjs, promise

This is a bit of an abstract question, as I don't have a particular use-case right now. I've noticed that if you resolve a promise with a promise

```
var deferredA = $q.defer();
var deferredB = $q.defer();
deferredA.promise.then(function(result) {
  // Will get here once promiseB has been resolved.
});
deferredA.resolve(deferredB.promise);
```

than promiseA isn't actually resolved until promiseB has been resolved (and then promiseA is resolved with the value of promiseB's resolution). However, what if I wanted to resolve with a value of an object with a "then" function, as:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.promise.then(function(result) {
  // Aim is to get here with result = {then:function(){}},
  // as though I had resolved a promise with a non-promise value,
  // but this function is never called
});
deferred.resolve({
  then: function() {
  }
});
```

then promiseA never actually gets resolved, as it assumed that the value is a promise, even though in the above example it's not, as in, it wasn't created with $q.defer(). There is an example plunkr at

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8XUKzxHtGBKBmgPed2q?p=preview

Is there a way around this? If so, how?

**Edit**: clarified deferred/promise & put in example "then" callbacks.

Comment: remove the then function from the object before calling resolve, and re-add it after?

Comment: The aim is to be able to resolve the promise with an object that contains a "then" function. The function wanting to use the resolved value of the promise may be in a completely different part of the code to that generating + resolving the promise, so I don't think that would really be possible.

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting that it doesn't detect an instance of `$q.defer().promise`. Perhaps this is a bug...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution

The `then` property that you're passing in is overriding the promise's `then` property.  You instead want to return your object from within the success callback of the angular promises `then` function like this:

```
$scope.resolvePromise2 = function() {
    deferred2.resolve({
      then: function(successCB) {
        successCB({myResult1:'result1',
                  myResult2:'result2',
                  'then':function() {console.log("got here")}});
      }
    });
  };
```

Using the above your message is now called and you can call the `then` function in your property:

```
promise2.then(function(result) {
   //Now we get here
   $scope.messages2.push('Promise 2 then callback. Result is:' + result);
   result.then();
});
```

Here's your updated [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V6L7gvts4OR1cgCVfHjY?p=preview).

### Issue/Why this works

Let's look at the Angular [`resolve()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/cb8061c75cdbcacd34b2570223e0cc2cbd8edb61/src/ng/q.js):

```
resolve: function(val) {
    if (pending) {
      var callbacks = pending;
      pending = undefined;
      value = ref(val);

      if (callbacks.length) {
        nextTick(function() {
          var callback;
          for (var i = 0, ii = callbacks.length; i < ii; i++) {
            callback = callbacks[i];
            value.then(callback[0], callback[1], callback[2]);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
```

Looking at `value = ref(val);` followed by `value.then(callback[0], callback[1], callback[2]);` we see that **Angular attaches the `then` function to the promise as a property** and that the object you passed in overrides that property.  So, in your case, the passed in `then` function is called instead of `deferred.promise.then(function(result)...`.

But **Angular calls your `then` function with the three callbacks** (success, error, notify): `value.then(callback[0], callback[1], callback[2]);` that were saved off in `var callbacks = pending;`

So the solution is to call the first "success" callback inside your `then` function and pass it your object including the `then` property you want returned.  Now the promise's `then` is called and receives your object including your `then` property

```
then: function(successCB) {
   successCB({myResult1:'result1',
              myResult2:'result2',
              'then':function() {console.log("got here")}});
}
```

Comment: This ends up with the resolved value of "result", and not the object {then:function(){}} in the "then" successCallback, which is what I'm wondering is possible. Perhaps a more realistic example is if there is some other data/functions in the value, say {myResult1:'result1',myResult2:'result2',then:function(){}}: I'm after myResult1, myResult2 and then all being available in the callback.

Comment: Are you looking to include the `then` for a different promise?  Or you are envisioning this to be recursive?  Where the `then` that resolve() calls includes another `then` function for the same promise, and if so what would be the terminating condition for the recursion?

Comment: I think none of those, with no recursion. There is some asynchronous action that generates an object that includes a `then` key, whose value is a function. There could also be other keys in the object as per my previous comment. The aim is to use this object as the fully resolved value of a promise. You can use `{'myResult1':'result1','myResult2':'result2'}` fine as a resolved value, but say you want to include `then` as a function as well `{'myResult1':'result1','myResult2':'result2','then':function() {}}`, then this will stop the promise ever being resolved, as per the original plunkr.

Comment: Thanks- that helped. I updated the answer (and the plunker) and hopefully improved the explanation.  It's kind of tricky to explain since there's both your `then` property and the Angular `then` property interacting.

Comment: I see it: it does what I wanted it to. Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that the inner `then()` isn't necessary and could be named anything you like; it's just a benign member of the object and not necessary for the synthetic `.then()` to function as a then. The fundamental thing is that  the synthetic `.then()` should accept `(successCB, errorCB, notifyCB)`, and that these functions should be called appropriately. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0P0qHiMWWdbXHbpeUi1r?p=preview).

Comment: Also, to allow deferred2's promise chain to work properly under error conditions, a well written synthetic `then()` should be written as a `try{...; successCB(...);} catch(e){errorCB(e)}` structure, otherwise an error will throw in the conventional way (to the console) and not be catchable with `.catch(errorHandler).`
Compare [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/bF8V0WQSWfXwD7hAMZTE?p=preview) 
with [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/yGUeY449Re4e19dV5V7G?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

You said that {then : function(){...}} isn't a promise. Well, accordingly to the promise A+ spec it does.

The spec states that promises should be interoperable, that said if a promise its resolved with a thenable object or if the onFulfill callback of a promise returns a thenable. The promise returned by the then method of the first promise will be resolved as soon as the promise returned by the onFulfill or passed as parameter to the resolve method gets resolved.

So your promise will never resolve because your thenable object never gets "resolved", and never calls its onFulfill callback.

That's a little confusing, but lets see on practice.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.promise.then(function(result) {
     // A promise should not be resolved with another
});

deferred.resolve({
    then: function() {
    }
});
```

The deferred's resolve method will see the then method of your object and think: "uhh, a sister promise, I will get resolved as soon it gets first".
So it will call your then function with a callback to actually resolve your promise.

this way:

```
yourThenable.then(function(spectedData){ 
     // Your promise will resolve as soon as this callback gets called
     // But your then function doesnt call the onFulfill callback
     // Thats why it never resolves
}, function(spectedData){ 
     // Also if this second parameter gets called your promise will be rejected
});
```

I don't know why you are doing this but you should'n resolve a promise with a thenable.
You can think in another ways to accomplish what you want.

Here is the easiest I can think:

```
deferred.resolve([{
   then: function() {
   }
}]);
```

The resolve method will lookup for a then method, but now your object is not a thenable, the 0 index of that array is.

```
deferred.promise.then(function(result) {
    // Now you have a result that is a Array
    // And the index 0 is your thenable object
});
```

But again, you should really think twice before keep doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to conclusion that it isn't possible.
You can only make sure you don't have `then` property by wrapping your object within another object without one:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.promise.then(function(result) {
  // Aim is to get here with result = {then:function(){}},
  // as though I had resolved a promise with a non-promise value,
  // but this function is never called
  result.result.then
}); 
deferred.resolve({ result: {
  then: function() {}
}});
```