# Return an object with a "then" function within "Promise.then()"

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, monads, option-type

Within my Node.JS application I have written a function (`findByReference`) that goes to a database and asynchronously yields a fetched database row. I have written this function using Promises. Additionally, I have written an implementation of the `Maybe` monad and want my `findByReference` function to yield an instance of `Maybe`.

My code looks like the below:

```
findByReference(r)
  .then(raw => raw ? Just(raw) : Nothing())
  .then(row => {
    (row instanceof Maybe) === true;
  });
```

Without going into what `Just` and `Nothing` mean, the implication of this (because of how I've written `Maybe`) is that the `row` variable in the above code **has a function on it called "then"**. To cut a long story short, it appears that Javascript is getting confused and is for some reason automatically calling MY "then" and instead of passing the `Maybe` is actually passing to the callback whatever MY "then" returns as the value of `row`. This is obviously leading to all manner of weird behaviour. If I simply remove the "then" function from my object then it all works as expected.

I am aware that if a `Promise.then` returns another Promise, then execution will pause until that promise is resolved. I have been unable to find any official documentation to back this up, but is it the case that this decision is simply based on the existence of a "then" function (the closest I have found is this https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises which refers to the return value as "something Promise-like"). If this is the case, it would be my understanding that "then" as a function name is basically a reserved word in Javascript? I have seen other implementations of Maybe (such as this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/data.maybe) that use the word "chain" for a similar thing - I wondered if this is why?

Can anyone shed any light on if my deduction here is correct and if so is there any workaround I can use other than renaming my function?

FYI the only other SO question I've found that touches this problem is this one - [Resolve promise with an object with a "then" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455632/resolve-promise-with-an-object-with-a-then-function) - but since that is angular-specific I don't believe this is a duplication.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Thenables* are assimilated, i.e. automatically flattened. This is the ugly face of duck typing.

Comment: [Wrap/unwrap thenables](https://github.com/then/thenable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...the row variable in the above code has a function on it called "then". To cut a long story short, it appears that Javascript is getting confused and is for some reason automatically calling MY "then"...

It's not confused. :-) This is the definition of how promises work. JavaScript's promises work according to the [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/), which uses this terminology:

> 1.1 “promise” is an object or function with a `then` method whose behavior conforms to this specification.
>
> 1.2 “thenable” is an object or function that defines a `then` method.

If you have an object passing through a promise chain that's a *thenable* but not a *promise*, it's incompatible with promises.

So yes, in a sense, the `then` property of objects passing through promise chains is "reserved" by the Promises/A+ spec. You'll need to wrap your `raw` value in an object that doesn't have a `then` (and then unwrap it later). Or if you can, rename `then` in your design to remove the conflict.

Comment: Haha yeah, calling a piece of software "confused" was a bit of a colloquialism, but I think you got my meaning :) Thank you for the great and fast answer, that explains it perfectly!